# Just want to compare last 5 characters of strings in array

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to check the last 5 character of the string with the data inside array. By default this is how i check it, but i couldn't do it with substr because the second parameter is an array.

```
if(in_array($row_order->number, $exploded_results[$row_order->log]){
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the value of $exploded_results[$row_order->log] is itself an array - you could try this, it's not pretty but it should work.

```
$found = false;
foreach ( $exploded_results[$row_order->log] as $item ) {
    if ( substr( $item, -5 ) == $row_order->number ) {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if ( $found ) {
...
}
```

You may also need to be more precise in the substr check in case you are mixing types in the if check by using ===.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the shortest it gets:

```
$match = array_first($exploded_results[$row_order->log], function($key, $value) use ($row_order){
    return substr($value, -5) == $row_order->number;
});

if($match){
    // found
}
```